# How to accelerate the speed of creating the huge matrix in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a huge matrix(60M X 3.1M),and I have written two script, one is try to use the gpu to speed up, the other is use the cpu to compute. I put the script on the SLURM and it has been running for almost a week, and it seems runs forever.I am a very beginner of python and data analyst, so I wonder if there is any chance to accelerate the process? Here is my code:

cpu version:

```
f = open('/etc/d_pair.txt', 'r') # the file contain 30M pair of diagnosis (two diseases in one pair)
f2 = open('/etc/ehr.txt', 'r')  # the ehr file, contain 60M patients and theirs diagosis
nf = open('/result/C_matrix.txt', 'w', newline='')
fline = f.readlines()
f2line =f2.readlines()  # a is list of all disease pair
All = []
for Id in f2line:  # each one of 60M patients
    b = Id.split(' ')  # turn each id and diagnosis into list
    nf.write(str(b[0]))
    nf.write(' ')
    for name in fline:  # a is list of all disease pair
        name = name.split(',')
        if name[0] in b:  # if the patient have both 2 d, give the value '1' to him/her
            if name[1] in b:
                nf.write('1')
            else:  # if the patient have 1 or 0 disease in those pair ,give the value 0 to him/her
                nf.write('0')
        else:
            nf.write('0')
        nf.write(' ')
    nf.write('\n')

f, f2, nf.close()
```

the gpu version:

```
import torch
import pandas as pd
torch.cuda.set_device(0)
f = open('/etc/d_pair.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('/etc/ehr.txt', 'r')
fline = f.readlines()
f2line =f2.readlines()  # a is list of all d pair
All = []
for Id in f2line:  # each one of 600M
    TIMES = []
    b = Id.split(' ')  # turn each id and diagnosis into list
    TIMES.append(int(b[0]))
    for name in fline:  # a is list of all d pair
        name = name.split(',')
        if name[0] in b:
            if name[1] in b:
                TIMES.append(1)
            else:
                TIMES.append(0)
        else:
            TIMES.append(0)
    All.append(TIMES)
c = torch.as_tensor(All).cuda()  # turn the 2-dimension list into tensor.
pc = pd.DataFrame(c).astype("int")
pc.to_csv('/result/matrix.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

I have read some similar questions, but some of their matrixs are not as huge as mine, some of them are aim to compute the matrix(dot and etc), so I am not sure if pytable or `scipy .sparse.csc.matrix` is suitable for my circumstance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just, why ? Why do you need something this huge ?

Comment: I'd advise you to use index operations instead of for loops as much as possible. They seem to be a lot faster. Also, you should probably test with a smaller matrix first, and once everything works as correctly and fast as you need, run the full thing

Comment: Since you seem to be working with medical diagnosis data, I assume your matrix is extremely sparse. This means you can use an interface for sparse matrices, e.g. [scipy.sparse.coo_array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_array.html#scipy.sparse.coo_array), which seems to be build for fast construction of sparse matrices. This may require conversions for further calculations, but the API should point out what to do. And honestly, it may be worth looking at alternative ways to model the task you want to solve, without the huge matrix.

Comment: Without having built a [mcve] for it myself, I think you might have luck trying [numpy memmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393041/2550406) to maybe help avoid memory swapping overhead, and to perform your operation as boolean filters on the matrix

Comment: @lucidbrot Thanks for your comments, I haver test it with a smaller matrix, but I need to traverse two reference flles  ,it might inevitable to use for loop.

Comment: Maybe you'd also be better off with an actual database that is made for huge data queries, instead of some numpy matrices. I would assume that a query made to some SQL database would do your job too, and probably be faster at it. But I don't consider myself an expert on your question, hence only some ideas as comments

Comment: @André Thanks for your comment, I will give a try on the coo.array.

Comment: @imperosol because I need to filer the 30m diagnosis, so that I can save some compute times in the following step.